# Rails - Associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations

I have a rails 4 app.

I have a profiles model and an organisation model.

The associations are:

profile.rb:

```
belongs_to :organisation
```

organisation.rb

```
has_many :profiles
```

Then in my show page in my profiles folder, I have:

```
<% unless @profile.organisation.title.empty? %>
    <%= @profile.organisation.title %>
<% end %>
```

When I try this, I get a no method error:

```
undefined method `title' for nil:NilClass
```

I don't understand this error. If there is no title, then there is nothing to display.

Can anyone see what I've done wrong?

Taking Miles' suggestion below, I tried changing my profiles show page to:

```
<% unless Organisation.find(@profile.organisation_id).title.empty? %>
                    <%= Organisation.find(@profile.organisation_id).title %>
                <% end %>
```

But, I get this error:

```
Couldn't find Organisation with 'id'=
```

The line starting with 'unless' is highlighted in the error message

Answer (score 1):

The `organization` of your `profile instance` is `nil` so when @profile.organization.title call it actually call `nil.title` and it is throwing the error(`undefined method`title' for nil:NilClass`)

You can use [try](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Object.html#method-i-try) to overcome in view level

```
<%= @profile.organisation.try(:title)  %>
```

Or you can give a validation check to overcome `nil` on `title` column on model level

on organization model

```
 class Organisation < ActiveRecord::Base
     validates :title, prescence: true
 end
```

Comment: This is the correct answer! Please try this @user2860931

Comment: Hi, I did try this. I get the same error as I got before I tried this. I think it has something to do with the point Miles made below.

Comment: Although Miles seems to have deleted his answer

Answer (score 0):

```
<%= @profile.try(:organisation).try(:title) %>
```

[Docs](http://apidock.com/rails/Object/try).

---

The actual problem is that your `@profile` doesn't seem to have an associated `organization`.

This can be solved in a number of ways; I would personally [use a `validation`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#presence) to make sure that your `organization` is being populated with each `profile` creation:

```
#app/models/profile.rb
class Profile < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :organisation
   validates :organisation, presence: true
end
```

Of course, this won't resolve your current issue.

To solve that, you need to make sure your `organisation_id` [foreign key](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foreign_key) is populated with the correct reference to the `Organization` model:

```
$ rails c
$ profile = Profile.find [[your id]]
$ profile.update organisation_id: [[org_id]]
$ exit
```

---

If you get it working, a cool trick you can use is [`delegate`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Module.html):

```
#app/models/profile.rb
class Profile < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :organisation
   validates  :organisation, presence: true
   delegate :title, to: :organisation, prefix: true #-> @profile.organisation_title
end
```

Delegate, as the name suggests, takes your request and sends it through to a dependent class. It works especially well with `belongs_to` because it removes the need to reference the associative object in between your parent and dependent classes.

Comment: Hi Rich. I have tried the way you suggested. I often use that for fields the may not be populated, but it's not working this time.  I'm not trying to force profile to have an organisation. I want it to show the organisation if there is one. There is a foreign key in my profile model for organisation_id.

Comment: I am going to try making this polymorphic and see if a different approach works out better for me